# Links in from Google try to load images not on my site... Very bizarre

Tags: php, security, http-status-code-404

I'll try to keep it short and simple here.

When users click on my organic Google links, they seem to be attempting to load images that are not on my site and have never been on my site. When I look in my IP Log, I see the user has loaded all the normal files and images, then I'll notice that two more images constantly attempt to load and are given 404 errors, as they aren't on my server.

When the user clicks on another page after landing, they attempt to load those images again. This has happened with the last dozen users or so. Here is an image of my IP log, I hope I've removed all identifiable material, but let me know if I haven't.

I looked in all my files in my file manager and see that none of them have been changed in quite some time.

My question is, what on earth is going on here? How can my site try to load something that isn't there, and that I haven't told it to load through my files. This is only occurring when Google links into my page.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some of your users are accessing your site with an iOS device.  Your site isn't trying to load something that isn't there, your visitors device is requesting a file that isn't there.  You can read more about what an Apple Touch Icon is and why you may want to create one here:
http://blog.karlribas.com/2012/05/how-to-create-apple-touch-icon-for-your.html